# How should I test a selenium application with capybara?

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara, remote-server

Here is my problem:

I am writing an application that **uses selenium-webdriver to connect to a site** a click/fill a bunch of things.

Obviously, I want to **test my code**... And this is where it gets difficult! How do I do this?

Here is my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

module MyModule
  Capybara.run_server = false

  describe "the method", :type => :request do
    it "should open a browser and go to the site" do
      MyClass.open_site("http://google.com")
      page.has_content? "Google"
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

module MyModule
  class MyClass
    def self.open_site(url)
      @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
      @driver.navigate.to url 
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Failures:

  1) the method should open a browser and go to the site
     Failure/Error: page.has_content? "Google"
     ArgumentError:
       rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
     # (eval):2:in `has_content?'
     # ./spec/integration/myclass_spec.rb:10
```

I can understand the test is confused because usually Capybara runs Selenium to vist a site and check that everything looks good. But here Selenium is running on its own as part of the code...

How could I tell rack-test to use the running Selenium as its application?

Is Capybara even the right solution to test this code?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One of the functions that you are using must be using a rack application.

The problem should not be with the line:

```
page.has_content? "google"
```

because that works fine for me with selenium driver. I suspect it is the way you have set up the driver.

I had a similar problem with running my capybara tests until I discovered these posts:[google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ruby-capybara/Mky_2Rwr0_o)

They gave me a few pointers to get my test running.
In the end I ended up having these lines to configure my tests. 
I am using chrome but Internet explorer and firefox would work this way too.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_ie do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome

Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did with my Sinatra application running MongoDB. Comment out the selenium code to try pure selenium without capybara. Install the `test-unit`, `capybara`, `capybara-webkit`, `selenium-webdriver` gems. For capybara-webkit do `brew install qt4` (mac) or install qt4 another way.

```
require './app'
require 'test-unit'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara-webkit'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class IntegrationTest < Test::Unit::TestCase  
  include Capybara::DSL

  def setup
    # Clear database first
    MongoMapper.database.collections.select { |c| c.name != 'system.indexes' }.each(&:drop)

    # For pure selenium: @b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    # For pure selenium: @w = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)

    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.default_selector = :css
    Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
    Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit  # Comment out to use :selenium
    Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application.new
    Capybara.app_host = "http://crowdfundhq.dev:3001"
    Capybara.server_port = 3001
  end

  def teardown
    # For pure selenium: @b.quit
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end

  def test_root
    # For pure selenium: @b.get "http://crowdfundhq.dev:3001"
    # For pure selenium: assert @b.page_source =~ /#pricing/

    # Change driver during test: Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver    

    visit("/")
    assert(page.body =~ /highlight/)
  end  
end
```